# Issues with migrating to new Roo version

Tags: java, spring, web, spring-roo

I've tried to migrate from Roo 1.2.3 to a new version which started to support new features of Java 7. But for both 1.2.4 and 1.2.5 versions when I've started Roo it's throwing:

StackOverflowError at com.github.antlrjavaparser.Java7Parser$RelationalE xpressionContext.shiftExpression(Java7Parser.java: 6610)

I've tried to give java more memory to use when it's running Roo. But that didn't help.

Can anyone give a suggestion on how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like java-parser implementation bug due to the new support to Java 7 features (see https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-3106).

Report it in https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO including a example to reproduce it so it can be solved.

Comment: Thanks for you're reply, created an issue here:  https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-3474